# Time series correlation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have some Particulate Matter sensors and CSVs with time series like:

Sensor A:

```
                     date           value
date                                     
2017-11-30 00:00:00  30/11/17 0.00     49
2017-11-30 00:02:00  30/11/17 0.02     51
2017-11-30 00:03:00  30/11/17 0.03     54
2017-11-30 00:05:00  30/11/17 0.05     57
2017-11-30 00:07:00  30/11/17 0.07     53
2017-11-30 00:08:00  30/11/17 0.08     55
2017-11-30 00:10:00  30/11/17 0.10     55
2017-11-30 00:12:00  30/11/17 0.12     58
2017-11-30 00:13:00  30/11/17 0.13     57
2017-11-30 00:15:00  30/11/17 0.15     58
....
2018-02-06 09:30:00    6/2/18 9.30     33
2018-02-06 09:32:00    6/2/18 9.32     31
2018-02-06 09:33:00    6/2/18 9.33     34
2018-02-06 09:35:00    6/2/18 9.35     32
2018-02-06 09:37:00    6/2/18 9.37     33
2018-02-06 09:38:00    6/2/18 9.38     30
```

I set date as index with:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%y %H.%M')
```

I would like to correlate different time windows between data from the same sensor AND from different sensor in similar time windows. I expect to know if I have same increase/decrease behaviour in some part of the day/days.
After setting "date index" I'm able to get "All PM value from 9am to 10am everyday from sensor A"

```
df.between_time('9:00','10:00')
```

1) **Problem 1: How to check correlation from same sensor but different days**: I filtered data 9/10am from two days in two DataFrame, but not always they're taken exactly at the same minute. I may have situations like this:

```
01-01-2018 (df01 - I removed data column)
2018-01-01 09:05:00     11
2018-01-01 09:07:00     11
2018-01-01 09:09:00     10
....


02-01-2018 (df02)
2018-02-01 09:05:00     67
2018-02-01 09:07:00     68
2018-02-01 09:08:00     67
....
```

Should I rename data column? I actually care that the third value from 01/01/2018 will correlate with the third value from the second window.

```
df01.corr(df02)
```

returns

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

2) **Problem 2: Correlate between different sensors** In this case I have 2 CVS files with PM values from two sensors. As Problem1 I would like to correlate same time windows from them.
Even in this case I expect some "Casual lag" between data but errors between minutes are fine and I want to check just values 'at right position'. Example:

```
Sensor A:
                         date           value
    date                                     
    2017-11-30 00:00:00  30/11/17 0.00     49
    2017-11-30 00:02:00  30/11/17 0.02     51
    2017-11-30 00:03:00  30/11/17 0.03     54
    2017-11-30 00:05:00  30/11/17 0.05     57

Sensor B:
                         date           value
    date                                     
    2017-11-30 00:00:00  30/11/17 0.00     1
    2017-11-30 00:02:00  30/11/17 0.02     40
    2017-11-30 00:04:00  30/11/17 0.03     11
    2017-11-30 00:05:00  30/11/17 0.05     57

AxB
                         date           valueA    valueB
    date                                     
    2017-11-30 00:00:00  30/11/17 0.00     49       1
    2017-11-30 00:02:00  30/11/17 0.02     51       40
    2017-11-30 00:03:00  30/11/17 0.03     54       11
    2017-11-30 00:05:00  30/11/17 0.05     57       57
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll try to address both of your questions together. This looks like a job for [`pd.merge_asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html), which merges on nearest-matching keys, rather than only on exact keys.

#### Example data

```
df1
date            value
30/11/17 0.00   51
30/11/17 0.02   53
30/11/17 0.05   65
30/11/17 0.08   58

df2
date            value
30/11/17 0.01   61
30/11/17 0.02   63
30/11/17 0.04   65
30/11/17 0.07   68
```

#### Preprocessing

```
df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date, format='%d/%m/%y %H.%M')
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date, format='%d/%m/%y %H.%M')
df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df1
                     value
date
2017-11-30 00:00:00     51
2017-11-30 00:02:00     53
2017-11-30 00:05:00     65
2017-11-30 00:08:00     58

df2
                     value
date
2017-11-30 00:01:00     61
2017-11-30 00:02:00     63
2017-11-30 00:04:00     65
2017-11-30 00:07:00     68
```

#### Merge DataFrames on nearest index match

```
merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='nearest')
merged
                         value_x  value_y
date
2017-11-30 00:00:00       51       61
2017-11-30 00:02:00       53       63
2017-11-30 00:05:00       65       65
2017-11-30 00:08:00       58       68
```

#### Correlations

Note that `df.corr()` doesn't accept data as an argument, so `df1.corr(df2)` doesn't work. The `corr` method computes pairwise correlation of the columns in the DataFrame you call it on ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)).

```
merged.corr()
          value_x   value_y
value_x  1.000000  0.612873
value_y  0.612873  1.000000
```

#### Notes

The above usage of `pd.merge_asof` keeps the index of `df1`; each row in `df1` receives its closest match in `df2`, *with replacement*, so if `df2` ever has fewer rows than `df1`, the result of `merge_asof` will contain duplicate values from `df2`. And the result will have the same number of rows as `df1`.

You mentioned that you really only care to compare rows by relative position, e.g., compare the 3rd value of `df1` to the 3rd value of `df2`. Instead of using `merge_asof`, you could simply ignore the time index once you've used it to obtain time periods of interest, and access the underlying numpy arrays with `df.values`:

```
# Get a 2D array of shape (4, 1)
df1.values
array([[51],
       [53],
       [65],
       [58]])

# Get a 1D array of shape (4,)
df1.values.flatten()
array([51, 53, 65, 58])

# numpy correlation matrix
pd.np.corrcoef(df1.values.flatten(), df2.values.flatten())
array([[1.        , 0.61287265],
       [0.61287265, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: Hi Peter! With merge_asof() I have the same value as value_y probably because value_x is get from day 1 and value_y from day 2, so the Nearest value is always the first from day2. Should I drop date from datetime index? How?

Seems promising the second way you mentioned in Notes. Can I correlate two arrays if their len is different (+- 1). I'm getting 'ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly'. I would like to compare equal arrays, avoiding extra values. I will correlate thousands arrays, how to automatically manage them? Thanks ;)

Comment: Hey @Davide, unfortunately Pearson and Spearman correlation require inputs of equal length. `merge_asof(df1, df2)` should be the cleanest way to take all of the rows in `df1` and merge each of them with the closest match from `df2`. If you go the numpy array route, you might have to manually trim the longer array to match the length of the shorter array, something like: `a2 = a[:b.shape[0]]; b2 = b[:a.shape[0]]` (this truncates either `a2` and `b2` to the length of the shorter of the two)