# two datasets, to find relation based on date range

Tags: python, loops, date-range

I have two datasets, one is with time of Volcanoes eruption, the second with Earthquake.
Both have "Date" column.
I would like to run somehow loop to find out based on the dates if Earthquake is linked to Volcanoes eruption.
The idea is that to check if the date of both events is close enough, lets say within 4 days range than create new column in Earthquake dataset and state yes or no (volcano related or no)....
I have no idea even how to start if that is even possible.
Here are the datasets:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727450/time-series-correlation-with-pandas

Comment: Generally, you will probably want [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all data combinations from both data sets, and [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to get the difference of those times. Then you'll just look for the data items where that timedelta is less that your required metric.